# Angular 1 isolated scope with outside ng-click bing to inner ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-show

I'm trying to make my first app with Angular 1 and I can't find how to pass the ng-click directive to isolated scope in my directive.

It's a weather app and those are my ng-clicks outside the directive:

```
<p class="btn" ng-click="celsius=false;fahrenheit=false">Celsius</p>
<p class="btn" ng-click="fahrenheit=true;celsius=true">Fahrenheit</p>
```

Inside directive are:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    Daytime temperature:
    <span ng-hide="celsius">{{ convertCelsius({ temp: weatherObject.temp.day }) }}</span>
    <span ng-show="fahrenheit">{{ convertFahrenheit({ temp: weatherObject.temp.day }) }}</span>
</div>
```

And my directive:

```
weatherForecastApp.directive('searchResult', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'directives/searchresult.html',
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            weatherObject: "=",
            convertCelsius: "&",
            convertFahrenheit: "&"
        },
```

Is there some method to pass this ng-click feature without refactoring to custom functions?

Comment: Not sure if I get exactly what you are trying to do, but you can call `convertCelsius / convertFarenheit` from `ng-click` itself. like `ng-click="celsius=false;fahrenheit=false; convertCelsius({ temp: weatherObject.temp.day });"`.

Comment: This two buttons switch temperature from Celsius to Fahrenheit by show/hide span. The function I want to pass is not converting but show/hide feature without creating a whole new function to do this.

Comment: Can you access the `weatherObject` from where you do the `ng-click`? If so you can use that object to set a flag in order to determine which one to show